# Creating a new Thread in Vaadin Java with GWT Graphics

Tags: java, multithreading, gwt, vaadin

I'm creating my first Vaadin Project and I have lots of problems understanding how it works. I created a new widget, that uses GWT Graphics and I drew some objects on the screen. However sometimes, instead of displaying the DrawingArea, my browser shows me this error

> Widgetset 'com.example.jtpwebapp.JtpwebappWidgetset' does not contain implementation for com.example.jtpwebapp.MyComponent. Check its component connector's @Connect mapping, widgetsets GWT module description file and re-compile your widgetset. In case you have downloaded a vaadin add-on package, you might want to refer to add-on instructions.

The other components are just fine. For example, this error shows up if I simply create a new Thread 
`new Thread() {
      public void run() {}
}.start();`

The widgetset re-compilation gives me no errors. I'm not changing the @Connect mapping nor editing the module file. 
There is really not much code to share, I created a new Vaadin widget using the Eclipse plugin and edited only in a few places.

I get this error also, when I try to make my widget implement a ClickHandler.

Comment: Have you specified the new widgetset to be used in your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT only contains an emulated subset of the Java runtime environment. Thread is one of the classes that's not included; JavaScript doesn't support threading so there's no way for the GWT compiler to generate the code for it. The full reference of what's supported is available [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html).

Now, missing emulation does unfortunately *not* show up at compile-time, but GWT does perform checks against the JRE emulation library. You just have to run your app in developer mode. The [Debugging Client-Side Code](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/clientside.debugging.html) section in Book of Vaadin does a pretty good job at explaining how to achieve that with Vaadin.